# "Flush Result : No Connectivity" Error for FBSDKAppEvents

Tags: ios, fbsdk, facebook-events

I have integrated `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` to track app events, I am calling `[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp]` in applicationDidBecomeActive: and enabling logs using `[FBSDKSettings enableLoggingBehavior:FBSDKLoggingBehaviorAppEvents]`

In logs it's logging following error

```
FBSDKLog: FBSDKAppEvents: Flushed @ 1473666575, 2 events due to 'Timer' - {
    "advertiser_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    "anon_id" = "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx";
    "application_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    event = "CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS";
    extinfo = "[xxx, xxx, xxx]";
    "url_schemes" = "[\"xxxxxxxx\"]";
}
Events: [
  {
    "isImplicit" : false,
    "event" : {
      "fb_mobile_launch_source" : "Unclassified",
      "_session_id" : "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
      "fb_mobile_app_interruptions" : 0,
      "_logTime" : 1473664599,
      "_ui" : "no_ui",
      "_eventName" : "fb_mobile_deactivate_app",
      "_valueToSum" : 155,
      "fb_mobile_time_between_sessions" : "session_quanta_2"
    }
  },
  {
    "isImplicit" : false,
    "event" : {
      "fb_mobile_launch_source" : "Unclassified",
      "_ui" : "no_ui",
      "_eventName" : "fb_mobile_activate_app",
      "_logTime" : 1473665765,
      "_session_id" : "96FA9509-AB21-475F-9F44-3005FE5D10BC"
    }
  }
]
Flush Result : No Connectivity
```

At end of log it's showing me error **Flush Result : No Connectivity**

Any one know why I'm getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts) guide FBSDK doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/ios) does not explain about each configuration required for tracking events